# making a jar file

Tags: java, executable-jar

I have written a code for client/server application. and I go to

> properties>packaging

for making a jar file for it. but when I run my server side and then client side ! it doesn't make the jar file for my application! what should I do? please help me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to make an executable jar

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

or alternatively you can write ant script to do the same

- [Document](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/JAR/basics/build.html)

Comment: where should I write it? I am beginner :)

Comment: sorry but really I am beginner would you please clarify this?"command prompt check document"

Comment: beginners should read the documentation.  A link was provided in the answer. Click it. Read it.

Comment: to startup check http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hwVuK0X-0P0 , If you can't understand document

Answer (score 0):

If you are a real beginner I suggest that you follow the 
[Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/)

Especially the one on [Jar files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/index.html)