# Java Console In Eclipse, But What If Using As Jar?

Tags: java

So,

I have made a little game in eclipse, it generates a rondom number from 1 - 1000 , when playing out of Eclipse, it plays in the eclipse console, but what if i want to play it without eclipse?
There is no console showing up?
Anyone a idea on how to fix this?
EDIT : I would like a new GUI instead of CMD.

Grts
PS: Tell me if you need a specific part of the source code

Comment: No need to show code. Use your OS command line to execute the jar.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4497579/making-a-jar-file-for-console

Comment: Its not a diplicate, i would like to use a new GUI for it, instead of CMD

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a new GUI." `java` executes from the command line, `javaw` executes in a window.

Comment: Like sort of a CMD,but in a Java window

Comment: [this](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) might be related... Haven't used it but maybe it will force show a console window for windowed applications?

Comment: In other words, you would like to execute the jar as an exe?

Comment: Not really a EXE, but a new window appears that works like CMD, but isnt CMD, because CMD looks bad for a game

Comment: @Joppe Dnb Cuyper - Sounds like maybe you want to learn about JTextArea ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the OP wants to reroute console output to a location of his choosing, not open an actual shell.

[Here is one way to reroute stdout.](http://another-lazy-blogger.blogspot.com/2008/04/did-you-ever-got-frustrated-with.html)

You can send it to a string, stream, file, etc. and then print it yourself into a window.

Answer (score 2):

1) You should probably export your program as a .jar file.

This isn't absolutely necessary - but it's better.  And it sounds like you've already done it :)

2) Be sure to specify the main class in Eclipse before you export the .jar

3) Once you *have* the .jar, you can:

```
   a) execute "java -jar myjar.jar" from a command prompt (for a console-mode program)    
   b) execute "javaw2 -jar myjar.jar" from a command prompt (for a Swing/GUI program)
```

4) You can also set a "file association" with javaw in Windows so that you can just double-click on the .jar to execute it:

- [Running JAR file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows)

Comment: You want a GUI, that's what "javaw" is for.  You don't want to type "javaw" in a command prompt, that's what a file association is for.  Or, for that matter, a .bat file and/or desktop shortcut are other options.  You want it, you got it ;) Simple as that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI, you will have to develop one yourself. There is no "Java Console GUI" that I've ever heard of.

Comment: My game uses a GUI, where you can click Start but it will still open as a CMD

Comment: Where do you "click Start?" If you already have a GUI, see @paulsm4's answer.